# Splitting the strings and store into new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame which as names column. Name column appear as below

```
Name

Tim, Brook, morgan han, wang, chen

adam, kate, ken fin, brad chun

Smith, leo

Elisa, Adam, Smith, Brad, james
```

I want to split the above names and store into new columns as below

```
Name      Name 1       Name 2         Name 3          Name 4           Name 5

Tim       Brook        Morgan         Han             Wang             Chen
Adam      Kate         Ken fin        brad chun
Smith     Leo
Elsa      Adam          Amith         Brad            James
```

I have more than 1000 rows in the column and having 20 columns. Want to split the names using function (def). Some rows has 5 names and other has 4, 3 or 2 names.

Used str.split and it's just giving the first name. But I am not sure how it split other names. Also used the function but it's not working

```
df[['Name']] = df.Name.str.split(', ', expand = True)
```

```
def clean(column_name):
   name=set()
    for name_string in df[column_name]:
        name.update(name_string.split(', '))
    name=sorted(name)
    return name
```

```
df[['Name']] = df[['Name']].apply(clean)
```

If I use the above function I am getting this error

KeyError: 'Tim, Brook, morgan han, wang, chen'

Please advise. I have gone through all the posts here but not successful.

Comment: why would you split `Morgan Han ` into two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pandas str.split with varying lengths of comma separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323622/using-pandas-str-split-with-varying-lengths-of-comma-separated-strings)

Comment: @Onyambu morgan and han are two different names

Comment: what about ken and fin or brad and chun? are they also two different or one?

Comment: @Onyambu again same error is coming with your code

Comment: @Onyambu ken fin is one person and brad chun is another person

Comment: @Jason here is a code: `df.Name.str.split(',| ').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(set(x))))`  does this do what you want?

Comment: So how do you know that ken fin is one person yet you say Morgan Han are two people? How do you distinguish?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194083/discussion-between-jason-and-onyambu).

Comment: @Jason. sorry cant chat outside here.  Just answer my question

Comment: @Onyambu names are differentiate using commas, for example adam, kate, ken fin, brad chun
adam is seperate name and kate is seperate name ..same for ken fin and brad chn

Comment: So Morgan Han is one person and not two people. You previously said it two people

Comment: @Onyambu my apologize. didn't notice

Comment: @Onyambu could you please suggest me your code in function. i want it to pass for other columns.. appreciate your help. basically, i am splitting the names and do so analysis PCA, Cluster analysis

Comment: if you are looking for a function then you could use `def clear(column): return df[column].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(set(x))))` then you can do `clear('Names')`

Comment: @Onyambu again error.. it's not working...

Comment: what error do you get? probably you used wrong column name, eg using Names instead of Name etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# to recreate example table
a = pd.DataFrame([str('Tim, Brook, morgan han, wang, chen')])
b = pd.DataFrame([str('Smith, leo')])
c = pd.DataFrame([str('Elisa, Adam, Smith, Brad, james')])
x = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
x.columns = ['Name']
```

Solution

```
x['Name1'] = x.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
x['Name2'] = x.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
x['Name3'] = x.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[2] if len(x.split(',')) > 2 else '')
x['Name4'] = x.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[3] if len(x.split(',')) > 3 else '')
x['Name5'] = x.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[4] if len(x.split(',')) > 4 else '')
```

Output

```
                                 Name  Name1   Name2        Name3  Name4  \
0  Tim, Brook, morgan han, wang, chen    Tim   Brook   morgan han   wang   
1                          Smith, leo  Smith     leo                       
2     Elisa, Adam, Smith, Brad, james  Elisa    Adam        Smith   Brad   

    Name5  
0    chen  
1          
2   james
```

You can implement a for-loop out of the solution, depending on the max number of names in each row. Hope this takes you somewhere. Cheers.